# Making changes to map entry value by index

Tags: dart

I understand that changing a map entry value can be done this way:

```
Map<String,int> myMap = <String,int>{"test",0};
myMap['test'] = 1;
```

So my question is simply whether it's possible to make changes using an index like this:

```
myMap[0] = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ben Konyi already stated there is no way to change *directly* a value in the map by the index, tough the default implementation of a `Map` is indeed a `LinkedHashMap` which preserve the insertion order, so, to change a an entry by its index you could retrieve the keys with `map.keys` and use the index there, for example:

```dart
  var map = {};
  map['a'] = 1;
  map['b'] = 2;

  map[map.keys.elementAt(0)] = 3;
  map[map.keys.elementAt(1)] = 5;  
  assert(map['a'] == 3);
  assert(map['b'] == 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't make changes by index in a `Map` as there's no promise of any ordering, so the idea of accessing one by an index doesn't make sense. Unless otherwise specified, creating a `Map` results in some form of hash map being used which does not preserve insertion order.

Explicitly using a [LinkedHashMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) will preserve insertion order (e.g., `map.entries` will return the key-value pairs in the order they were added to the map), but there's no way to make changes by index.

Comment: If you're familiar with `Flutter` I'd like to take your insight on this matter.

Comment: Depends what you're looking for, but I can probably help.